# Android Kotlin Coroutine on screen rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am launching a coroutine that after a specified delay display a counter value on the screen.

```
job = launch(UI) {
    var count= 0
      while (true) {
        textView.text = "${count++}"
        delay(200L)
      }
   }
```

Now on screen rotation I want UI keeps getting updated with correct counter value. Does someone has any idea how to resume the job on configuration(e.g. screen rotation) change.

Answer (score 1):

> Does someone has any idea how to resume the job on configuration(e.g. screen rotation) change.

Your job never stopped running, but you keep holding on to and updating a `TextView` which is no longer showing on the screen. After the configuration changed, your activity and its entire view hierarchy got scraped.

While technically you can configure your app not to recreate the activity on rotation, Google strongly discourages you from doing that. The app will seem to work for the case of rotation, but then will break on another kind of config change like timezone, location etc. You just have to bite the bullet and make your app work across activity recreation events.

I made my coroutines work across activity recreation by relying an a `Fragment` in which I set

```
retainInstance = true
```

This means that your fragment instance survives the death of its parent activity and, when the new activity replaces it, Android injects your fragment into it instead of creating a new one. It does *not* prevent the destruction of the view hierarchy, you must write code that updates the fragment's state to reflect these changes. It helps because it allows you to keep the fragment's state instead of bothering with parcelization.

On configuration change, your fragment will go through these lifecycle events:

1. `onDestroyView`
2. `onCreateView`

It doesn't go through `onPause`/`onResume`, this only happens when you switch activities or exit the app. You can start your coroutine in `onResume` and cancel it in `onPause`.

As of the recently released version 0.23 of `kotlinx.coroutines`, `launch` became an extension function: you must call it in the context of some `CoroutineScope` which controls the resulting job's lifecycle. You should bind its lifecycle to the fragment, so let your fragment implement `CoroutineScope`. Another change is that the `UI` coroutine context is now deprecated in favor of `Dispatchers.Main`.

Here's a brief example that demonstrates all the points I mentioned:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment, CoroutineScope {
    private var textView: TextView? = null
    private var rootJob = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext 
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + rootJob

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_id, container, false)
        this.textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        this.textView = null
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        this.launch {
            var count = 0
            while (true) {
                textView?.text = "$count"
                count++
                delay(200L)
            }
        }    
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        rootJob.cancel()
        rootJob = Job()
    }
}
```

Now, as the view hierarchy gets rebuilt, your coroutine will automatically fetch the current instance of `textView`. If a timer tick happens to occur at an inconvenient moment while the UI is being rebuilt, the coroutine will just silently skip updating the view and try again at the next tick.

Answer (score 0):

By default rotation kills the activity and restarts it.  That means your textview will no longer be the one on screen, it will be the one belonging to the old activity.

Your options are:

1)Add a configSettings to your manifest to turn off this behavior.

2)Use something that can persist around activity restarts like a View Model, a loader, an injected event bus, etc.

Personally unless you have a different layout for portrait and landscape I'd just go with number 1, its easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in ViewModel instead of Activity.

Comment: I think I did answer question wrong way. Basically my question is more related to kotlin coroutine's job restarting. Can i store Job itself and resume it?

Comment: You still need a place to store the job.